# Can not add SOAP Web Reference

Tags: visual-studio-2010, soap, web-reference

I have a .wsdl file installed on my local server. However, when I try to add it through VS it can not find it at the installed path(root of localhost). I know the file is there because I can see it when I browse through the filesystem. 
Is there something I am missing when I try to add it as a web reference? I've tried localhost, 127.0.0.1, and the IP of the server.

Comment: Just use the file system path: `C:\wherever\whatever.wsdl`.